# Hard drive on-disk read cache

Tags: c, caching, disk

I know that hard drive (note, I'm talking about magnetic ones, NOT SSDs) have internal on-disk RAM caches. These are typically around 64MBs. I'm trying to understand what is a typical read buffering policy for these caches.

Naively, I assumed that latest reads are cached. I tried to do a simple test on a secondary disk, Seagate ST32000645NS HDD, using fio and also a small piece of code I wrote. This disk is not even mounted, so nothing should interfere with these tests. Both repeatedly read from a small range of sectors (a few MBs) that is well contained within the on-disk buffer size. Both tests use O_DIRECT, to eliminate the effects of the host OS buffer. Since modern disk interfaces have Gb/s throughput, and all but the initial reads from the disk should be cached on the on-disk buffer, I expected to see throughputs of 100s MB/s. Yet I'm getting measly results on the order of 1MB/s, indicating that no read caching is done on disk. I even tried to repeatedly read the same 4KB over and over again, and still got similar poor results.

I looked in dmesg, which says "sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA". So there doesnt seem to be a configuration problem here. Can anyone shed some light on what may be the issue with the on-disk read cache here? perhaps some underlying default config in the driver is telling the device to ignore the read cache?

edited - here are the relevant pieces of code.

fio script code which I run several times in a row:

```
[global]
bs=4k
rw=randread
random_generator=lfsr
direct=1
ioengine=libaio
iodepth=1
direct=1

[device]
filename=/dev/sdb
filesize=64M
size=64M
```

my code:

```
char name[20] = "/dev/sdb";
int fd = open(name, O_RDWR | O_DIRECT);
if (fd < 0){
    printf("failed openning %s. errno %d\n", name, errno);
    return -1;
}

int pagesize=getpagesize();
printf("pagesize %d\n", pagesize);

char* realbuff=malloc(4096+pagesize);
char* buf=((((int unsigned)realbuff+pagesize-1)/pagesize)*pagesize);

int res, off, total_reads = 100000;
for (i=0; i<total_reads;i++){
    off = 0;

    res = lseek(fd, off, SEEK_SET);
    if (res != off){
        printf("seek res %d, expected %d\n. i %d errno %d", res, off, i, errno);
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }

    res = read(fd, buf, pagesize);
    if (res != pagesize){
        printf("read only %d bytes, expected %d\n. i %d errno %d", res, pagesize, i, errno);
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you use `O_RDWR`?  Do you get similar performance if you use `O_RDONLY` instead?

Comment: No difference with O_RDONLY. I planned to write data before reading it to disk at one point, so I used O_RDWR.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, using `O_DIRECT` on small I/O sizes performs poorly, thus if you want to see the effect read cache try issuing a big I/O. It would be helpful to share `fio` test script or your micro benchmark code to be able to assist you.

And, you could try setting read-ahead option in `hdparam` which is well documented in [this link](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/Tune-Your-Hard-Disk-with-hdparm)

---- updated ----

Since direct I/O can be thought of as synchronous I/O, the I/O must be completed before processing incoming I/Os. And, small I/Os would take up much time in making context switches and setting up registers for DMA operations.

Following graph shows the bandwidth of direct I/O test fio script. I changed the I/O sizes from 4KB to 8MB using the provided fio script. As it shows that issuing small I/O sizes using direct I/O shows very poor performance, and as the I/O size increases the performance also increases.

Since host page cache is not working due to direct I/O, the system can not exploit the readahead feature and the data has to be fetched from the disk surface or from the disk cache on the device making slow and cumbersome context switches.

[image: direct I/O: file size 64MB, I/O size from 4 KB to 8MB]

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help. I've edited my post to include the relevant pieces of code (@paddy you also asked for this).

As for O_DIRECT - I can understand why O_DIRECT will be slow for small reads on an HDD for small random accesses. But if the read is for buffered data, why should it matter?

Comment: NB: direct I/O can be asynchronous in fio if the ioengine used is asynchronous. You can see this in action on Linux when using ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --iodepth=16 against a block device - the queue depth reported by fio when it finishes will typically be greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Does upping the depth, doing I/O sequentially and changing size (both smaller and bigger) make a difference? [Wikipedia suggests the hard disk's cache is only used for readahead/readbehind and write caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_buffer). If this is so you won't get a benefit from the disk's cache reading only one random I/O at any given time even if you are re-reading the same areas.